# Display empty buckets when grouping by two columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am looking to populate empty buckets when grouping on two columns. Here is the setup and resultant dataframe:

```
bins = [-np.inf,0,10000,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,np.inf]  # include infinity value as the endpoint to the bins
labels = ['0K','10K', '20K','40K','60K', '80K','100K','> 100K']
df_Done_Major['Bucket'] = pd.cut(df_Done['rfq_qty'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
# Polpulate empty buckets with 0 adjacently
df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket = df_Done_Major.groupby(['Bucket', 'currency_str'], as_index=False)['Bucket'].size()
```

The resultant df as expected:

```
display(df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket)

Bucket        currency_str  count
10K                AUD       9
60K                AUD       1  
60K                USD       1
100K               AUD       1
100K               USD       1
> 100K             AUD       57
> 100K             CAD       4
> 100K             USD       5
```

The desired result:

```
currency_str    Bucket     Count
AUD               0K         9
                  10K        0
                  20K        0
                  40K        0
                  60K        1
                  80K        0
                  100K       1
                  > 100K    57
USD               0K         0
                  10K        0
                  20K        0
                  40K        0
                  60K        1
                  80K        0
                  100K       1
                  > 100K     5
CAD               0K         0
                  10K        0
                  20K        0
                  40K        0
                  60K        0
                  80K        0
                  100K       0
                  > 100K     4
```

My attempt:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket.index.levels[1], df_Done_Major['Bucket'].cat.categories])   
df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket  = df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
```

No counts are being returned on the labels. Any suggestions as how to return the counts of each trade?

```
display(df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket)

AUD  0K        0
     10K       0
     20K       0
     40K       0
     60K       0
     80K       0
     100K      0
     > 100K    0
CAD  0K        0
     10K       0
     20K       0
     40K       0
     60K       0
     80K       0
     100K      0
     > 100K    0
EUR  0K        0
     10K       0
     .
     .
     .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue relating to the grouping and index being referenced

```
df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket = df_Done_Major.groupby(['currency_str','Bucket'], as_index=False)['Bucket'].size()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_Done_Major_Fill_Empty_Bucket.index.levels[0], df_Done_Major['Bucket'].cat.categories])
```